Does the A320 have an audible A/THR disconnect sound?
Say for example, the Autothrottle was engaged (while Autopilot not engaged), but for some reason was disconnected, is there an audible cue for this event? What sound does it make?

Listen.

Yes, there are both visual and audible cautions triggered when the A/THR is disconnected. The details depend on whether it was a standard disconnect (via the instinctive disconnect buttons on the thrust levers or by setting the thrust levers to idle) or a non-standard way:


Standard diconnection triggers temporary ECAM message and caution light. Single
chime sounds.
Non standard disconnection triggers caution light and ECAM message removed only by
a pilot action. Single chime sounds.



(Airbus A320 FCOM - Autoflight - Flight Guidance - A/THR Disconnect Caution)
